# Column wise Record display

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pivot

I am trying to display my sql data in column wise. currently the output is

```
Customer Name       Amount          Date
XYZ                 1200            2015.01.01
XYZ                 600            2015.01.02
```

But i want to display like:

```
           2015.01.01       2015.01.2
XYZ        1200             600
```

My code is as below:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <table border="0" id="info">

    <?php
        $conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','test');
        if(!$conn) die("Failed to connect to database!");
        $status = mysql_select_db('tulient', $conn);
        if(!$status) die("Failed to select database!");

        $sql = mysql_query("select * from add_deposite where CUSTOMER_NAME like '%$term%' and DATE between '$term1' and '$term2'");


        $rs = mysql_query("select * from add_deposite where CUSTOMER_NAME like '%$term%' and DATE between '$term1' and '$term2' ");
        $CUSTOMER_NAME = "";
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
                {

                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td><div align="left">'.$row['CUSTOMER_NAME'].'</div></td>';
                    echo '<td><div align="left">'.$row['AMOUNT'].'</div></td>';

                    echo '<td><div align="left">'.$row['DATE'].'</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }

            ?> 
           </table>
```

Your valuable advice is necessary to complete my task.
thanks in advance.

Ripon

Comment: Could you please try to re-format how you'd like it to look? It's not quite obvious as it is now.

Comment: This is called "pivoting," just so you know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: It's a multidimensional array, in which the dates become the keys, and the amounts the values

Comment: I guess to retrieve the data as you desire from sql itself, your query would look something like this:

select customer, sum(amount), date from add_deposite group by customer, date